# Can't install VLC on Ubuntu, and can't Play films

Tags: apt, video, vlc

In the past days, I used VLC to watch video tutorials. But, occasionally, the **video couldn't play correctly and had screen stuck problems**. I thought that I perhaps needed to update my system and the software. So I used the command:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

trying to fix problem, but, unfortunately my computer also held those problems.
The system and VLC are both on the last version.

Last night, I used Ubuntu Software to remove VLC. And from some forums I found that I should run:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove vlc
$ sudo apt-get auto clean"
```

etc (because I wanted to uninstall it completely to reinstall later). **But after uninstalling VLC, I am incapable of enabling it again.**

This the reason why I can't install VLC again.

```
yann@yann-Matrimax-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for yann: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
yann@yann-Matrimax-PC:~$ ^C
```

[image]

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I run **VLC 2.2.5**. Could you can help me to solve those troubles? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try removing it completely and installing it directly from the binaries.

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then download the binaries from http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.8/vlc-2.2.8.tar.xz

Save the file wherever you want to install it. Then, uncompress it:

```
tar –xzf vlc-2.2.8.tar.xz
```

You can run the program directly if you want, without installing it by:

```
./vlc
```

Or, install it with:

```
./configure
make install
```

And finally run it:

```
./vlc
```

The file INSTALL inside the tar.xz file contains more information abut the installation.

Good luck!

Comment: Sir, Thank for your advice, I attempt in another computer of those commands. and successfully to reinstall  VLC. although I don't know whether the same operation on my personal PC will be how? I will still trying.

Comment: Keep us informed about your re installation status. Someone could have the same problem as you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try another player, try:

```
sudo apt-get install totem
```

Or explain why you "incapable to enable it again" in detail.